# Take multiple Arrow functions as Promise and print the values of all resolves from the Arrow functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, arrow-functions

I am trying to print

> [ 'First call!', 'Second call!' ]

My Code:

```
function get(apiCalls) {
    return Promise.all(apiCalls)
}

//------------ START
let promise = get([
    () => Promise.resolve("First call!"),
    () => Promise.resolve("Second call!")
]);

if (promise) {
    promise.then((result) => result).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
//------------ END
```

But I am getting output:

> [ [Function], [Function] ]

The code snippet from **START** to **END** cannot be changed

Answer (score 5):

You are passing an array of functions to `Promise.all`, but it expects an array of promises. Either call the functions:

```
return Promise.all(apiCalls.map(f => f()))
```

or pass promises:

```
let promise = get([
    Promise.resolve("First call!"),
    Promise.resolve("Second call!")
]);
```